Hello, I am trying to replace a multi channel 12v switching relay board (automotive application) to something like a MOSFET or IC
Project details.
Automotive application 12V ignition system.
Currently using a 12V multi channel relay board in a NC configuration. All  source channels (pulled low by ECU) are wired to the COM terminals, NC terminals of relay wired to negative terminal of ignition coils.
Positive terminal of ignition coil wired to ignition 12V.
Relay coils negative side bridged and connected to common ground.
Positive side of relay coils bridged and triggered via a 12V switching module.
Load is 12v current 3-6A
I wish to replace the relay board with MOSFET’s or an IC to reduce size and moving parts.
From research so far, Power MOS would be most suitable for current and voltage requirements, however I would require P-channel depletion MOSFETS which don’t exist. Is there a series of IC I could use that has multiple channels or could I use N-channel depletion MOSFETS?
